# unable to install react in ubuntu where error is displayed and I cant understand it?

Tags: reactjs, linux, ubuntu, command

when i type this command to install react package in ubuntu :npx create-react-app my-app

this error is displayed //

Creating a new React app in /home/x/Desktop/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/rollup (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/x/.npm/_logs/2021-04-16T13_04_47_820Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from /home/x/Desktop
Done.

any suggestion please ?

Comment: Timeout. It may be an internet problem.

Comment: i dont think si since i tried it multiple times

Comment: Please follow the steps [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started).

Comment: yes dear i was actually working on this tutorial but i stuck at the command :#npx create-react-app my-app   , it is displaying error